# Check user if is in chat room Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have models: 

**ChatRoomMembers** 
**ChatRoom**
so I want to check if auth user is in chat room

my relationships:

> **ChatRoom**:

```php
    public function chatRoomMembers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ChatRoomMember::class);
    }
```

> **ChatRoomMembers**:

```php
    public function chatRoom()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ChatRoom::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Comment: I don't have any relation in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created relationship in User Model:

```php
    public function chatRooms(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
           ChatRoom::class,
           ChatRoomMember::class,
           'user_id',
           'id',
           'id',
           'chat_room_id'
        )->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
```

and I am getting only this user chat rooms

Answer (score 0):

In user model add below relationship

```
public function chatRoomMember(){

   return $this->hasMany(ChatRoomMembers::class);
}
```

and in code

```
auth()->user()->chatRoomMember->count()
```

or

```
auth()->user()->chatRoomMember->exists()
```

Comment: I tried other relationship, 

`public function chatRooms(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            ChatRoom::class,
            ChatRoomMember::class,
            'user_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'chat_room_id'
        )->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }`

Comment: if its working then post your answer and accept your answer so it might help someone